# Subset using R Studio

Tags: r, time-series

How do I compute the ADF test with R if I do not want all my observations in it?
My time series contains 3000 observations. Now I want to compute the ADF test for example for the 200 first observations. I tried the following: `ur.df(x, lags=5, selectlags="AIC", type="drift", subset=1:200)` from the package `urca`, `library(urca)`, but I get the following error message:

```
Error in summary(ur.df(Vstoxx, lags = 5, selectlags = "AIC", type = "drift",  : 
  Fehler bei der Auswertung des Argumentes 'object' bei der Methodenauswahl
for function 'summary': Error in ur.df(Vstoxx, lags = 5, selectlags = "AIC", type = "drift", subset = 1:200) : 
  unused argument (subset = 1:200)
```

where the german part translates to: Error during evaluation of the argument 'object' in the method selection.
Here is a small data sample:

```
x
1   14.4700
2   14.5100
3   14.4200
4   13.8000
5   13.5700
6   12.9200
7   13.6800
8   14.0500
9   13.6400
10  13.5700
11  13.2000
12  13.1700
13  13.6300
14  14.1700
15  13.9600
16  14.1100
17  13.6300
18  13.3200
19  12.4600
20  12.8100
21  12.7200
22  12.3600
23  12.2500
24  12.3800
25  11.6000
26  11.9900
27  11.9200
28  12.1900
29  12.0400
30  11.9900
31  12.5200
32  12.3500
33  13.6600
34  13.5700
35  13.0100
36  13.2400
37  13.4900
38  13.9900
39  13.1900
40  12.2100
41  12.8900
42  12.3500
43  12.8600
44  12.5700
45  11.9300
46  11.7200
47  12.0000
48  12.5300
49  13.4700
50  12.9600
51  13.3500
52  12.4900
53  14.5700
```

Many thanks

Comment: Could you please include your `library` / `require` statement(s)? Also, providing a sample of your dataset is much more likely to get you answers... either use `dput` or `head`. Thx.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I edited my original post and added a small data sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a `subset=` parameter, you can simply use indexing to subset `x` (see my example below)

```
x <- c(14.4700, 14.5100, 14.4200, 13.8000, 13.5700, 12.9200, 13.6800,
       14.0500, 13.6400, 13.5700, 13.2000, 13.1700, 13.6300, 14.1700, 13.9600, 
       14.1100, 13.6300, 13.3200, 12.4600, 12.8100, 12.7200, 12.3600, 12.2500, 12.3800, 
       11.6000, 11.9900, 11.9200, 12.1900, 12.0400, 11.9900, 12.5200, 12.3500, 13.6600, 
       13.5700, 13.0100, 13.2400, 13.4900, 13.9900, 13.1900, 12.2100, 12.8900, 12.3500, 
       12.8600, 12.5700, 11.9300, 11.7200, 12.0000, 12.5300, 13.4700, 12.9600, 13.3500, 
       12.4900, 14.5700)

library(urca)

# We'll use only the 50 first elements in x
ur.df(x[1:50], lags=5, selectlags="AIC", type="drift")
```

Output:

```
############################################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root / Cointegration Test # 
############################################################### 

The value of the test statistic is: -2.1741 2.3635
```

Comment: although the way OP's x printed, it looks like a data frame, and this example is a vector, so `x[1:50]` when x is a data frame would give much different results

Comment: Yes then one only need to add an index or var name, like `x[1:200, 1]`

Comment: `ur.df` takes only vector or matrix argument.